Can quantum computers eventually be programmed "normally"?
They tell us that eventually quantum computers will break all current encryption methods. On the other hand, current quantum computers are programmed at a very low, mathematical level and for very small problems.
Will quantum computers in the foreseeable future be programmable via more conventional means, using their "all results at the same time" capability as just a kind of Super-Multi-Threading? Like
public String GetPasswordFromHash(String sha512hash) {
 foreach_quantum_parallel_at_once(String passwd in String.all() )
   if (Calcsha512Hash(passwd)==sha512hash)
     return(passwd);
  return(null);
}

If yes, how far away from that point are we? Do we just need more and more reliable QBits or fundamental improvements?

Welcome to QCSE. Who is “they” in “they tel us”?

Quantum computers do not work by just trying all solutions in parallel. This is such a common misconception that it is even the tagline of Scott Aaronson's blog, a professor of computer science. The answer is therefore no. Getting an exponential speedup depends on the structure of the specific problem, you can't get it in a black box way. Grover's algorithm, on the other hand, can be applied to an arbitrary problem in a black-box way, but it only gives you a square-root speedup. It's possible to prove that this is the best one can do.

It is also not true that quantum computers will break "all current encryption methods". They will break ones based on the hardness of factoring and the discrete logarithm, and possibly some more, but there's no generic "break crypto" algorithm. The one-time-pad, for example, is unbreakable.

I feel like the question can be interpreted in two ways:
When will the lay-person be able to use quantum computers at a high level?
Of course you can create a high-level quantum programming language, which just provides a shiny cover on the very low, mathematical level.
For example, the particular syntax you suggest would "compile" into running Grover's algorithm with some oracle function that computes the SHA-512 hash. Software libraries like qiskit aren't far off from this point. There are a whole slew of various low-level options to choose from, but your language can simply specify sensible defaults.
The trickiest part is constructing the oracle as a quantum operation given only a classical boolean expression. I'm fairly certain there exists a systematic construction that could be automated, but I'm not sure whether such a systematic construction will necessarily be efficient (ie. any faster than just looping through each password classically).
Of course, we'll need large-scale quantum computers with systematic and robust error correction before anyone can really use it casually like this. Anyone's guess when that will be, but ten years seems like a plausible number.
When will we have a "programmable" quantum computer?
The idea of a "programmable" computer conveys the idea of a block of memory in the computer itself, which determines the course of computation and the ultimate output (i.e. a Turing machine).
Meanwhile, the high-level program in the previous section is living in a classical computer, and the majority of the logic (including the construction of the oracle, composition of a total quantum circuit, transpilation into a pulse schedule, and then the post-processing of measurement results afterward) is presumably being resolved on the classical computer. The quantum computer is just reacting in its quantum way to the given pulse schedule, and being measured.
In order for me to say we have a "programmable" quantum computer, we would have to set up some kind of clock which periodically uses the state of qubits in the machine to determine what pulses to apply next. Actually, there are plenty "hybrid" quantum-classical algorithms which do this. I suppose you could think of the "quantum-classical complex" as a programmable quantum computer, and we certainly have that today.
A programmable pure quantum computer is conceivable - with some kind of clock that automatically adjusts the pulse schedule based on the state of the memory - but it'd be a bit weird 'cause the program you'd load into memory would be purely classical, and (without a much more sophisticated architecture) so would the pulse schedule. I don't expect many people are thinking about this, and I'm not sure there's any reason to.
